# Export audio with frames?

Tags: export, animation, sound, video

I have a list of image frames and a wav file, is there a way to export a mov file with an audio track?

```
imgs = Import["ExampleData/clip.mov", "ImageList"];
audio = Import[ "ExampleData/rule30.wav" ];
Export["~/video_with_sound.avi", {imgs, audio}, {{"Frames", "Sound"}}]
```

which results in

[image]

I'm hoping someone knows a hidden option or something, because from the docs, "Sound" is not an element for any of the supported video MIME types. However, according to the docs AVI is fully supported (AVI is an acronym for Audio Video Interleave) so there should be a way to do this.

Comment: I'm pretty sure there is no way to export any kind of movie file with an audio stream. You will probably have to use a separate application.